# How do I match and replace all characters that are not a number or a dash as first character with a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to remove all non numeric characters in the whole string or dash (-) characters that are not at the start of the string with a regex. How do I do this?

Closest I've come is `[^\d\-]` but I can't figure out how to only allow - at the start of the string.

```
stringToReplace.replace(/[^\d\-]/g, '')
```

The use of this and what I'm trying to achieve is to allow negative integer numbers and remove everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could negative lookahead for `^` when matching a dash, and alternate with `[^\d-]` (note that `-` doesn't need to be escaped in a character set):

```
stringToReplace.replace(/(?!^)-|[^\d-]/g, '')
```

https://regex101.com/r/1xmeeV/1

I think the logic might be clearer to read if you use a replacer function, though: optionally match `-` at the beginning of the string, and in the rest of the string, match non-digit characters and replace with the empty string:

```js
const stringToReplace = '-12gh4-5';
const result = stringToReplace.replace(
  /^(-)?(.*)/,
  (_, start, rest) => start + rest.replace(/\D+/g, '')
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is check whether each word starts with a number or a dash. To do this there are 2 steps:

1. Get each word individually
2. Check word

   2.1 If word doesn't start with a number or a dash, replace the first symbol with a dash and return.

   2.2 If word does start with a number or a dash, return the word as is.

```js
function startDashOrNumber(stringPart) {
    if (stringPart.search(/^(-|\d)/i) < 0) {
        return '-' + stringPart.substr(1);
    }
    return stringPart;
}
function breakIntoWords(str) {
    return str.replace(/\S+/igm, startDashOrNumber);
}
//TEST
console.log(breakIntoWords("-Lorem 1ipsum dolor sit lamet"));
```